# Wrong TableLayout Weight

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm using a table layout inside a linear layout and the first row turns out fine but the consecutive rows are entirely the wrong weight despite setting both of them. I'm not sure if this is an issue with the version of Android Studio I'm running or maybe it doesn't work with kotlin... is there any way to fix it? I've updated everything.

I know Table Layout is pretty dated but I **seriously** do not want to use Constraint Layout, I absolutely hate it. It's way too much work for what I'm making.

activity_main.xml

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_weight="8" android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TableRow android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                    android:text="@string/loan_amount"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView15" android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_weight="3"/>
            <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:id="@+id/loanAmount" android:layout_weight="7"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView38" android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <TextView
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView39" android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <TextView
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView40" android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set your `layout_width` to **0dp** in the `TableRow` items. If you want to center the content add `android:gravity="center"` to the TextViews.

Code without gravity would look like this:

```
<TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
                android:text="TextView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView38" android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
                android:text="TextView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView39" android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
                android:text="TextView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView40" android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </TableRow>
```